# Jquery plugin development, attach a browser event and methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Ok so i'm learning to write plugins and the jQuery site for plugin authoring is damn confusing. I'm really trying to figure out how to add methods to my plugin that will fire based on a browser event. So basically I have a plugin that builds out a swipeable slide show for a mobile device. When the device is rotated I need it to rebuild the slideshow for the new dimensions. Right now I have it so it builds it the first time but I can't (a) figure out to add methods for different functions and (b) bind events to those specific methods. here's my code.

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.jCarousel = function( options ) {
    var empty = {} 

    var defaults = { 
        height: $(window).height(),
        width: $(window).width(),
        count: 1,
        amount: $('.swiper', this).length,
        thisone:this,
    };

    var options = $.extend(empty, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

        options.thisone = this;

        amount = $('.swiper', this).length;
        holdWidth = options.width * options.amount;

        $('.swiper', this).height(options.height);
        $(this).height(options.height);
        $('.swiper', this).width(options.width);
        $(this).width(holdWidth);
        $('.swipe_slide',this).width(holdWidth);

      //==================================================================================================================
        //==================================================================================================================

        $('.swiper', this).each(function(i) {
            var nwidth = options.width*i;
            $(this).css('left',nwidth);
        });
        //==================================================================================================================
        //==================================================================================================================     
        //==================================================================================================================
        //==================================================================================================================

        $('.swipe_slide', this).swipe(function(evt, data) {
            if(data.direction=='left'){
                //alert('count: '+options.count+" amount: "+options.amount);
                if(options.count != options.amount){
                    moveWidth = options.count * -options.width;
                    $('.swipe_slide',options.thisone).css( "left" ,moveWidth );
                    options.count++
                }else{
                    return    
                }
            }else{
                if(options.count!=1){    
                    moveWidth = moveWidth+ options.width;
                    $('.swipe_slide',options.thisone).css( "left" ,moveWidth );
                    options.count--
                }
                else{
                    return
                }
            }
        });    
        //==================================================================================================================    
        //==================================================================================================================  
        });
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', $.fn.jCarousel);
```

You'll have to refactor your plugin a bit so that the function stores the options that are passed into it, otherwise running the function again on orientation change will reset the options to the defaults.